# What is the best way to activate sequentially 2 or more data pipeline on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have two distinct pipelines (A and B). When A has terminated I would like to kick off immediately the second one (B).

So far, to accomplish that I have added a `ShellCommandActivity` with the following command:

`aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id <my pipeline id>`

Are there other better ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of indicator files (zero byte files) & Lambda to loosely couple the two data pipelines. You need to make the following changes -

Data Pipeline - Using a shell command touch a zero byte file as the last step in the data-pipeline in any of the given s3 path

Create a lambda function to watch for the indicator file and activate the Data Pipeline2

Note - This may not be very helpful if you are looking at a simple scenario of just executing two data-pipelines sequentially. However, it's helpful when you want to create an intricate dependency between pipelines viz. you have a set of Staging jobs (each corresponding to one pipeline) and you want to trigger your Data-mart Jobs or derived table jobs after all the staging jobs are completed.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to have your lambda function listen for an S3 Event, rather than poll S3 directly for the trigger file. Or have Pipeline A post its "completed" event directly to SNS/SQS and let that trigger your lambda.